# Overwriting global variable in python

Tags: python

I have python file with series of function defined there (sample below: file1.py). There are alot of global variables in this file. Some of these global variables are passed through different functions in file1.py.

I generally import file1.py to different file and use the function (as shown in example file2.py). But, for one specific application, I want to override variable password declared in file1.py while using file1.py. is there any way to do the same? (I tried what I have shown in file2.py) I can't do any changes at file1.py end as it belong to a different developer..

```
file1.py
HOST = "https://host_for_data_api/"
PASSWORD = "DKB"
Global_2 = 2
Global_3 = 3

def func1():
    auth()

def f(auth):
    print("does authentication")

def func3(pass=PASSWORD):
    print(pass)

file2.py
import file1 as f
f.PASSWORD = "ABC"
```

EDIT: What I want to see if i call func3 it should print "ABC"

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to achieve. The code you posted should work.

Comment: Please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?
You can redeclare/reset the variable in your func e.g. if the file is file1 or whatever condition you need.

```
GLOB_VAR = "Some string"

def some_fun():
    global GLOB_VAR
    GLOB_VAR = "Some other string"

some_fun()
print GLOB_VAR
```

Comment: Reset the global variable  in func3 like I showed in the code above. Just write global PASSWORD  = 'ABC'

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the default value of a parameter after function declaration (At least it's not easy), because `str` is immutable. you can change the `file1.func3` to:

```
def func3(passw=None):
    if passw is None:
       passw = PASSWORD
    print(passw)
```

or wrap the original func3 with a lambda:

```
orig_func3 = f.func3
f.func3 = lambda passw="ABC": return orig_func3(passw)
```